# How can I store HTML in a Doctrine YML fixture

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, yaml, fixtures

I am working with a CMS-type site in Symfony 1.4 (Doctrine 1.2) and one of the things that is frustrating me is not being able to store HTML pages in YML fixtures. Instead I have to create SQL backups of the data if I want to drop and rebuild which is a bit of a pest when Symfony/Doctrine has a fantastic mechanism for doing exactly this.

I could write a mechanism that reads in a set of HTML files for each page and fills the data in that way (or even write it as a task). But before I go down that road I am wondering if there is any way for HTML to be stored in a YML fixture so that Doctrine can simply import it into the database.

**Update:**

I have tried using `symfony doctrine:data-dump` and `symfony doctrine:data-load` however despite the dump correctly creating the fixture with the HTML, the load task appears to 'skip' the value of the column with the HTML and enters everything else into the row. In the database the field doesn't show up as 'NULL' but rather empty so I believe Doctrine is adding the value of the column as ''.

Below is a sample of the YML fixture that `symfony doctrine:data-dump` created. I have tried running `symfony doctrine:data-load` against various forms of this including removing all the escaped characters (new lines and quotes leaving only angle brackets) but it still doesn't work.

```
  Product_69:
    name: 'My Product'
    Developer: Developer_30
    tagline: 'Text that briefly describes the product'
    version: '2008'
    first_published: ''
    price_code: A79
    summary: ''
    box_image: ''
    description: "<div id=\"featureSlider\">\n    <ul class=\"slider\">\n        <li class=\"sliderItem\" title=\"Summary\">\n            <div class=\"feature\">\n              Some text goes in here</div>\n        </li>\n    </ul>\n  </div>\n"
    is_visible: true
```

Comment: WHat does your code look like ? Do you get any error ? *I've used HTML in Doctrine fixtures without any trouble nor doing anything special*

Comment: err... doesn't `symfony doctrine:data-dump` do the job?

Comment: Doing `symfony doctrine:data-dump` will create a fixture with all the data just fine however the `symfony doctrine:data-load` task appears to ignore the HTML content and just insert the rest of the item. Interestingly enough it doesn't leave the field null, just blank (so I assume Doctrine tried to insert `''` into the column as a value).

I don't get any errors or warnings from the command line when I run `symfony doctrine:data-load`.

Comment: Please post here the EXACT fixture code. Looks like quote is missing.

Comment: Updated, the closing quote got accidentally removed but that fixture is exactly what is generated from data-dump.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you use this format below?

```
  Product_69:
    name: 'My Product'
    Developer: Developer_30
    tagline: 'Text that briefly describes the product'
    version: '2008'
    first_published: ''
    price_code: A79
    summary: ''
    box_image: ''
    description:   |
        <div id="featureSlider">
            <ul class="slider">
                <li class="sliderItem" title="Summary">
                    <div class="feature">Some text goes in here</div>
                </li>
            <ul>
        </div>
    is_visible: true
```

Comment: Why is the question now community wiki? I like getting rep for bothering to answer questions when I could be doing something else.

Comment: In my case it was also necessary to escape the double quotes, e.g. <div id=\"featureSlider\">

Comment: For me i need to escape < and > on each tag when i get the Invalid token error. eg : \<p\>Foo bar\</p\> And it works !

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem, and I found out that there is not a problem in **storing** html in the database but in **outputting** html.  Symfony seems to output text with html as a string with quotes around it to prevent cross-site-scripting.  However, they have a way to render the raw text.  Instead using:

```
<?php echo $htmlText ?>
```

Use:

```
<?php echo $sf_data->getRaw('htmlText') ?>
```

You can find out more about this in *A Gentle Introduction to symfony: Chapter 7 - Inside The View Layer*:

http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer